# MySQL JOIN not filtering on WHERE clause with < > operators, since moving from MySQL 5.6 -> 5.7

Tags: mysql, left-join, mariadb, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

We're upgrading our DB systems to MySQL 5.7 coming from MySQL 5.6 and since the upgrade a few queries have been running really slow.

After some investigating we narrowed it down to a few JOIN queries which suddenly don't listen to the 'WHERE' clause anymore when using a 'larger than' > or 'smaller than' < operator. When using a '=' operator it does work as expected. When querying a large table this caused a constant 100% CPU usage.

The queries have been simplified to explain the issue at hand; when using explain we get the following outputs:

```
explain 
        select * from TableA as A
                left join
                (
                    select
                        DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%H:%i:00') as `time`
                    FROM
                        TableB
                    WHERE
                        created_at < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 HOUR) 
                )
                as V ON V.time = A.time
```

**Output**

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  A   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10080   100.00  NULL
1   SIMPLE  TableB  NULL    index   created_at  created_at  4   NULL    488389  100.00  Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

As you can see, it's querying/matching **488389** rows and not using the where clause since this is the total records in that table.

And now running the same query but with a *LIMIT 99999999* command or using the '=' operator:

```
explain 
        select * from TableA as A
                left join
                (
                    select
                        DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%H:%i:00') as `time`
                    FROM
                        TableB
                    WHERE
                        created_at < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 HOUR) LIMIT 999999999
                )
                as V ON V.time = A.time
```

**Output**

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY A   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10080   100.00  NULL
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    244194  100.00  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
2   DERIVED TableB  NULL    range   created_at  created_at  4   NULL    244194  100.00  Using where; Using index
```

You can see it's suddenly only matching '244194' rows which is a part of the table, or with the '=' operator:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  A   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10080   100.00  NULL
1   SIMPLE  TableB  NULL    ref created_at  created_at  4   const   1   100.00  Using where; Using index
```

Just 1 row, as expected.

So the **question now** is, have we been querying in a wrong way and
   just now finding out while upgrading or have things changed since
   MySQL 5.6? It seems odd that the **=** operator works, but the **<**
   and **>** are ignored for some reason, unless when using a LIMIT?..

We've searched around and couldn't find the cause of this issue, and we'd rather not use the limit 9999999 solution in our code for obvious reasons.

**Note** When running just the query inside the join, it works as expected as well.

**Note** We've also ran the same test on MariaDB 10.1, same issue.

Comment: Have you updated the indexes? It claims to be using the index,

Comment: Yes, indexes are present and updated on the fields in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7, derived tables (sub-queries in FROM clause) will be merged into the outer query if possible.  This is usually an advantage since one avoids that the result of the sub-query is stored in a temporary table.  However, for your query, MySQL 5.6 will create an index on this temporary table that could be used for the join execution.

The problem with the merged query is that the index on TableB.created_at can not be used when the column is a parameter to a function.  If you can change the query so that the transformation is made to the column on the left side of the join, an index can be used to access the table on the right side.  Something like:

```
   select * from TableA as A
            left join
            (
                select created_at as time
                FROM TableB
                WHERE created_at < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 HOUR) 
            )
            as V ON V.time = func(A.time)
```

Alternatively, if you can use inner join instead of left join, MySQL can reverse the join order, so that the index on tableA.time can be used for the join.

If the subquery use LIMIT, it can not be merged.  Hence, by using LIMIT you will get the same query plan as was used in MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Thanks! This finally lead to solving our issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `explain` `row`-output is merely a guess on how many rows it will hit. It is based upon statistical data, that has been resettet with your update. And if I had to guess how many rows of all your existing rows are older than yesterday 9pm, I would too guess its closer to "all rows" than to "just some rows". The reason why 'limit 99999999' is displaying another rowcount is the same: it just guesses the limit will have an effect; in this case, mysql guesses it will be **exactly** half of the rows (what would be, if true, a strange coincidence), and of course, it doesn't actually look at the limit-value, since 999999999 will not limit anything when you only have 500k rows; and even the "1" in case of "=" is just a guess (and might more often be 0 than 1, and maybe sometimes more).

This estimate will help choose the correct execution plan, and being wrong in this guess is just a problem if it would choose the wrong one; your execution plan looks fine though, and there are not many option to do it otherwise. It does exactly as expected: Scan the index for all dates using the index on created_at. Since you do a left join, you cannot skip values from `tableA` even if you would start with the inner query, so there is really no alternative execution plan available. (The optimizer actually have been changed in 5.7., but here is doesn't have an effect.)

If that is your actual query, there is no real reason why it should be slower than before (only regarding this query; there are of course a lot of general performance options that might have an indirect effect, like caching strategies, buffersizes, ..., but with standard options, it should not have an effect here).

If not, and you e.g. actually use additional columns from `TableB` in the subquery (it is often hard to guess which maybe important things have gotten "simplified away" in questions), and thus need access to the actual table, it might depends on how your data is structured (or better: in what order you added it). And you might try `Optimize table TableB` to make your table and indexes fresh and new, it can't hurt (but will lock your table for a little while).

With mysql 5.7., you now can add generated columns, so it might be worth a try to generate a cleaned up column `time as DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%H:%i:00')`, so you don't have to calculate it anymore. And maybe add it to your index, so you don't have to sort it anymore to improve the `block nested join`, but that may depend on your actual query and how often you use it (spamming indexes increases overhead and uses space).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but if i run the queries mentioned above I see the same results, 230ms with the limit 99999 clause, and about 3-4minutes without it. While the same queries finish around ~230ms on MySQL 5.6 as well. 

I tried optimising both tables, alas to no effect. We could look into the generated columns indeed, only without indexes then since these queries are being ran every minute.

Comment: @Nick Well, it shouldn't. With an estimate at ~30mb/s hdd speed, 4 byte per row (in the index, and mysql says it uses the index) it would mean you could read 500k values 2700 times in 180 seconds (not counting that it will be cached after the first read), so something else is going on. If you are happy that it works with `limit`, it's fine, otherwise try: `set @@profiling = 1; do your query; show profile; do your 2nd query; show profile; show profiles; set @@profiling = 1;` to see what the time is spent on. And run your `limit` query first/run it twice, so it will not be favoured by cache.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` unless you need the 'right' table to be optional.

Avoid `JOIN ( SELECT ... )`.  Although 5.6 and 5.7 added some features to handle it, it is usually better to turn the subquery into a simpler `JOIN`.

Your time expression leads to 9pm yesterday; did you mean "3 hours ago" instead?

See if this gives the desired results and runs faster:

```
select  A.*, DATE_FORMAT(B.created_at,'%H:%i:00') as `time`
    from  TableA as A
    JOIN  TableB as B  ON B.time = A.time
    WHERE  B.created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR   -- (assuming "3 hours ago")
```

As for 5.6 vs 5.7...  5.7 has a new, 'better', optimizer, based on a "cost model".  However your particular query makes it virtually impossible for the optimizer to come up with good costs.  I guess that 5.6 happened on the better `EXPLAIN`, and 5.7 happened on a worse one.  By simplifying the query, I think both optimizers will have a better chance at performing the query faster.

You do need these indexes:

```
B:  INDEX(time, created_at) -- in that order
A:  INDEX(time)
```